# provision to pre-validate the angular Slick-grid draggable grouping feature. Also remove specific column from grouping programmatically

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I have to add a column after validation from my application. Is there any pre-validation available for adding columns in pre-header for grouping?
And is there any method to remove a particular column from a pre-header?

Software versions:

- Angular : 7.3.5
- Angular-Slickgrid : 2.19.0
- TypeScript : 3.1.6
- Windows 10
- Node : 10.16.3
- NPM : 6.9.0

Comment: the docs are directly in the plugin, see for yourself the [draggable grouping plugin](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/plugins/slick.draggablegrouping.js), I don't think the plugin support what you're looking for though, you could contribute that enhancement... On a totally out of topic subject, your versions of everything are kinda old, just sayin ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.